# Why can't i apply borderRadius to this React bootstrap tab?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap

I have this tabbed content and i want to apply a border radius. If i add style={{borderRadius: "10px"}} it does nothing. Works everywhere else. There's nothing about Tabs in scss either that would overwrite this.

No matter where i try to apply the border radius it doesn't have any effect at all. Am i missing something?

Here's the tabs.

```
   <Col md={6} xl={4} className='m-b-30' >
                        <Tabs defaultActiveKey="today" style={{borderRadius: "10px"}} >
                            <Tab eventKey="today" title="Today" >
                                {tabContent}
                            </Tab>
                            <Tab eventKey="week" title="Tomorrow">
                                {tabContent}
                            </Tab>
                            <Tab eventKey="all" title="Active Status">
                                {tabContent}
                            </Tab>
                        </Tabs>
                    </Col>
```

Below is the tabs content.

```
const tabContent = (
            <Aux>
                <div className="media friendlist-box align-items-center justify-content-center m-b-20"style={{border: "solid 1px black"}}>
                    <div className="m-r-10 photo-table">
                        <a href={DEMO.BLANK_LINK}><img className="rounded-circle" style={{width: '40px'}} src={avatar1} alt="activity-user"/></a>
                    </div>
                    <div className="media-body">
                        <h6 className="m-0 d-inline">Evelina Tofan</h6>
                        <span className="float-right d-flex  align-items-center">DO &nbsp;<i className="fa fa-caret-down f-22 m-r-10 text-c-red"/></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="media friendlist-box align-items-center justify-content-center m-b-20">
                    <div className="m-r-10 photo-table">
                        <a href={DEMO.BLANK_LINK}><img className="rounded-circle" style={{width: '40px'}} src={avatar3} alt="activity-user"/></a>
                    </div>
                    <div className="media-body">
                        <h6 className="m-0 d-inline">Anel Stancov</h6>
                        <span className="float-right d-flex  align-items-center">DO &nbsp;<i className="fa fa-caret-down f-22 m-r-10 text-c-red"/></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="media friendlist-box align-items-center justify-content-center m-b-20">
                    <div className="m-r-10 photo-table">
                        <a href={DEMO.BLANK_LINK}><img className="rounded-circle" style={{width: '40px'}} src={avatar2} alt="activity-user"/></a>
                    </div>
                    <div className="media-body">
                        <h6 className="m-0 d-inline">Denis Sultu</h6>
                        <span className="float-right d-flex  align-items-center">12PM - 9PM &nbsp;<i className="fa fa-caret-up f-22 m-r-10 text-c-green"/></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="media friendlist-box align-items-center justify-content-center m-b-20">
                    <div className="m-r-10 photo-table">
                        <a href={DEMO.BLANK_LINK}><img className="rounded-circle" style={{width: '40px'}} src={avatar2} alt="activity-user"/></a>
                    </div>
                    <div className="media-body">
                        <h6 className="m-0 d-inline">Vasile Mirzan</h6>
                        <span className="float-right d-flex  align-items-center">9AM - 6PM &nbsp;<i className="fa fa-caret-up f-22 m-r-10 text-c-green"/></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="media friendlist-box align-items-center justify-content-center m-b-20">
                    <div className="m-r-10 photo-table">
                        <a href={DEMO.BLANK_LINK}><img className="rounded-circle" style={{width: '40px'}} src={avatar1} alt="activity-user"/></a>
                    </div>
                    <div className="media-body">
                        <h6 className="m-0 d-inline">Andra Danila</h6>
                        <span className="float-right d-flex  align-items-center">9PM - 6AM &nbsp;<i className="fa fa-caret-up f-22 m-r-10 text-c-green"/></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="media friendlist-box align-items-center justify-content-center">
                    <div className="m-r-10 photo-table">
                        <a href={DEMO.BLANK_LINK}><img className="rounded-circle" style={{width: '40px'}} src={avatar1} alt="activity-user"/></a>
                    </div>
                    <div className="media-body">
                        <h6 className="m-0 d-inline">Maria-Alexandra Serban</h6>
                        <span className="float-right d-flex  align-items-center">DO<i className="fa fa-caret-down f-22 m-r-10 text-c-red"/></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </Aux>
        );
```

Comment: Did you tried with !important to be sure that something is not overriding it?

Comment: Can you tell me from where are you importing "Tabs" component?

Comment: You can always resolve issues like this by using the DOM inspector tool in the browser.

Comment: Yeah i tried that too, still no effect.

Comment: i'm importing from react-bootstrap

Answer (score 2):

Tabs is a component, by specifying style you are sending a prop named style which is an object with a property named border radius. If tabs (component) doesn't use/implement that prop (in this case named "style", for clarification it could be named anything else) no effect will be made.

You can specify style to a JSX/HTML element to have the desired effect or modify the Tabs component so it uses the "style" prop to forward the style to some of it's children (Other components or JSX elements)